# Where to place machine's system-wide private ssh deploy key?

Tags: ssh, users, git

I'm following the directions at https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.16/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys , which includes `Run the ssh-keygen procedure on your server` to generate a private/public ssh key pair.

I would like apps on my server (such as `git`) to use this private key with just `ssh`, instead of `ssh -i` or `ssh-add`, so it must be placed at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

However, this is a private key that lives on my server; the key belongs to the server machine, not to any particular user.

Where should I place system-wide private ssh keys?

Comment: But why would apps on the GitHub server need that key? That's for deploying from GitHub to somewhere else. Only GitHub should need it.

Comment: There are no apps on any GitHub server.  I'm talking about running processes on my own server.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to share a key between multiple users?

Comment: To decouple the key from any particular user.  If I place the key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and then decide to get a brand new username or quit or die tomorrow, and my `~` directory is deleted, the server should still continue to function.

Comment: If you were to get a brand new username tomorrow, you'd still have to configure whatever services that currently use your username to use the new one. They aren't going to automagically start using the new username. So add key management to that configuration. A private key readable by anyone is an oxymoron.